# JavaScript and Array's

Tags: javascript, arrays

*EDIT* I originally posted this with my version of the J.S but it's so far off no one can even help so i'm starting over. Here is the pseudocode i have done that needs to be translated into a Javascript program. Any help is appreciated!

I am a beginning programmer i understand this code will have multiple errors, that's why i am here. Array's and loops have given me much trouble while trying to learn them and especially with formatting them in JavaScript. The things i know are incorrect or still need i commented out i still need them, i also know i'm not passing anything i just can't seem to wrap my head around how to get them there. I'm also not sure if while gather input i'm using alter and prompt correctly. In the display function the spacing is necessary for when it will be displayed. Corrections and explanations are greatly appreciated.

```
Module main()
//Declare local variables
Declare endProgram = “no”
While endProgram == “no”
    Declare Real notGreenCost[12]
    Declare Real goneGreenCost[12]
    Declare Real savings[12]
Declare String months[12] = “January”, “February”, “March”, “April”, “May”, “June”, “July”, “August”, “September”, “October”, “November”, “December”

    //function calls
    getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months)
    getGoneGreen(goneGreenCost, months)
    energySaved(notGreenCost, goneGreenCosts, savings)
    displayInfo(notGreenCost, goneGreenCosts, savings, months)

    Display “Do you want to end the program? Yes or no”
    Input endProgram
End While
End Module

Module getNotGreen(Real notGreenCost[], String months[])
Set counter = 0
While counter < 12
    Display “Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for”, months[counter]
    Input notGreenCosts[counter]
    Set counter = counter + 1
End While   
End Module

Module getGoneGreen(Real goneGreenCost[], String months[])
Set counter = 0
While counter < 12
    Display “Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for”, months[counter]
    Input goneGreenCosts[counter]
    Set counter = counter + 1
End While   
End Module

Module energySaved(Real notGreenCost[], Real goneGreenCost[], Real savings[])
Set counter = 0
While counter < 12
    Set savings[counter] = notGreenCost[counter] – goneGreenCost[counter]
    Set counter = counter + 1
End While
End Module
 Module displayInfo(Real notGreenCost[], Real goneGreenCost[], Real savings[], String months[])
Set counter = 0
While counter < 12
    Display “Information for”, months[counter]
    Display “Savings $”, savings[counter]
    Display “Not Green Costs $”, notGreenCost[counter]
    Display “Gone Green Costs $”, goneGreenCost[counter]
End While
End Module
```

Comment: Are you using nodejs, or is this supposed to work in the browser?

Comment: @JazzCat I believe browser. I just have it attached to a container to run.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code. I'd suggest you'd try https://www.freecodecamp.com/

Comment: Putting aside the syntax errors,  Javascript is single threaded so the whiles and general work flow above will not work as expected. As @JazzCat suggests, I 'd take a look at the many, many free resources on-line to begin your exploration with javascript (in browser or node).

Comment: @JazzCat okay thanks I'll check it out. People on here have been very helpful before so I wanted to post it here.

Comment: I recommend to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Comment: No worries @KylieMarino , good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- Currently the program creates a few variables and functions that
  don't seem to interact
- Most of the edits below are not optimal -    there are parts that
  could be done by much simpler means (i.e.    counter++) - But thats
  for you to learn =P
- I made quite a few    assumptions of what you wanted the program to
  do, they might be    wrong, they might be right

  ```
  var notGreenCost = [];    //Array lengths don't need to be specified
  var goneGreenCost = [];
  var savings = [];
  var months = ["January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June"];

  //A boolean value (true | false) would suit this better as opposed to "yes"/ "no"
  var endProgram = false; 
  var option = 0;

  /* You dont need main functions in javascript
   * migrated everything to be global :/
   * Delete:
      function main(){
          // Move this (made it global): var endProgram = "no"; 
      }
  */
  // I don't think this is meant to be initMonths..
  // Maybe something like getOptions?
  function /*initMonths*/getOptions(){
      while (endProgram == false){  //lowercase while
          //Because prompt would block everything else until it gets input
          //we probably want to move the prompt to be after the alerts
          alert("options:"); //Clarity
          alert("1 to enter data");
          alert("2 to display data");
          alert("3 to write data to a file");
          alert("4 to read data from a file");
          //Alter global "option" to take the value of the prompt
          option = prompt("What would you like to do? Type:"); 
          //} //I assume you want the rest of the code in this while loop - otherwise it will loop forever

          // Delete this bracket (its unmatched): { 
          // Delete return statement as it will stop the function return option; 
          // Delete this bracket (its unmatched): }

          //Create a variable to take the value of prompt (this should be outside the while loop) but it seem clearer for explanation purposes to be here
          var toEnd;
          toEnd = prompt("Do you want to end the program (enter yes or no)");
          // Javascript uses != for "not equal to" and && for "AND"
          while (toEnd != "no" && toEnd != "yes") {
              toEnd = prompt("Please enter a value of yes or no");
          }

          //I think you want to assign the value of toEnd to endProgram
          // Note the the below is not the only/best way to do it
         if(toEnd == "no") {
             endProgram = false;
         } else if(toEnd == "yes") {
             endProgram = true;
         }

        // While use brackets not End s
        //        End While
        //    End While
      }//End while loop here
  }
  ```

Javascript in a browser cannot alter files - writeToFile, readFromFile have all been removed

I believe you want months to be global, if it is then initMonths is unnecessary

getNotGreen:

```
function getNotGreen(){
    //You don't need to specify types in Javascript
    /*Integer*/ var counter = 0 
    while (counter < 6){ //lowercase while
        //I'm assuming you want to combine the values of "Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for" and  months[counter] - This is done by using the + sign
        //Im also assuming you want to read the value into notGreenCost
        //.push adds a value to a array
       notGreenCost.push(prompt("Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for" + months[counter]))

       //Returning here makes the rest of the function redundant
       //}
       //return notGreenCost[counter];
       //}
       //Javascript does not use Set
       // Note that below is not the only/best way to do it
       /*Set*/ counter = counter + 1
     } //End the while loop here
}
```

getGoneGreen:

```
function getGoneGreen(){
    //Counter should probably be local (not global) - use var
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < 6){//lowercase while
        //I'm assuming you want to combine the values of "Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for" and  months[counter] - This is done by using the + sign
        //Im also assuming you want to read the value into notGreenCost
        //.push adds a value to a array
     goneGreenCost.push(prompt("Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for" + months[counter]));
        //See above (getNotGreen)
        //}
        //return goneGreenCost[counter];
        /*Set*/ counter = counter + 1;
   }//End while loop here
}
```

energySaved:

```
function energySaved(){
    //Counter should probably be local (not global) - use var
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < 6){//lowercase while
        savings[counter] = notGreenCost[counter] - goneGreenCost[counter]
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}    //I assume you want to end energySaved here?
```

displayInfo:

```
function displayInfo(){
    //Alert produced individual boxes, i assume you want the following in a single window?
    // "\n" is a line break
    alert("SAVINGS     NOT GREEN    GONE GREEN        MONTH\n"+
          "_________________________________________________\n");
    //Counter should probably be local (not global) - use var
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < 6){//lowercase while
        alert( "$" + savings[counter] + "$" + notGreenCost[counter] + "$" + goneGreenCost[counter] + "" + months[counter]);
        counter = counter + 1;   
    } 
}    //I assume you want to end displayInfo here?
```

Comment: You're amazing! How long have you been doing this? Truly aspire to have knowledge like yours.